# Finding p value between two rasters in R

Tags: r, raster, tiff

How can a p value be obtained between two rasters?

I currently have two rasters, and I would like to compute a p value.
I convert both into dataframes with na.rm=T.

```
df1<-as.data.frame(r1,na.rm=T)
df1<-as.data.frame(r2,na.rm=T)
cor.test(df1$gc,df2$ip)$p.value

Error in cor.test.default(df1$gc,df2$ip)) : 
  'x' and 'y' must have the same length
```

Even if I dont go for the na.rm, this comes

```
 df1<-as.data.frame(r1)
    df1<-as.data.frame(r2)
    cor.test(df1$gc,df2$ip)$p.value

    [1] 0
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass a numeric vector to `cor.test()`. You are getting to that converting to a data.frame and getting the column, but it's probably easier to use the *raster* function `values()`:

```
set.seed(666)
r1 <- raster(matrix(rnorm(100), 10, 10))
r2 <- raster(matrix(rnorm(100), 10, 10))
cor.test(values(r1), values(r2))$p.value
```

0.07144313

The error when you remove `NA` is because the two vector do not have the same length, i.e. in one vector you have more `NA` cells than in the other. Depending on many `NA` you have, the p-value you get at the end (0) may be important or not. Did you try making a simple boxplot or distribution plot of the values in both rasters? This may help you understand if the p-value is simply an artefact of too many `NA`.

```
d <- data.frame(
   x = c(values(r1), values(r2)), 
   y = c(rep(1, ncell(r1)), rep(2, ncell(r2)))
)
boxplot(d$x ~ d$y)
```

/Emilio